# What is behind my plasterboard!? Studs appear to be random in position and length!

Tags: drywall, studs, television, mount

I'm hoping to mount a 23kg tv on an articulating mount to a plasterboard wall and I gather they are supposed to have studs running vertically behind them with even spacings... BUT, stud finder is absolutely useless and just says the entire wall is one giant electrical wire with edges everywhere... and if you try the tapping the wall technique you may find a solid part amongst all the hollow bits - which you assume is a stud - but it doesn't run vertically up and down it just ends after a little bit like it's more of a "patch" than a vertical beam..!

Does anyone know what this indicates?

Also does anyone know how far behind the actual surface of the wall the brick wall is ? I'm starting to think it might easier to screw the tv mount all the way through the plaster into the brick wall if this is even possible. My other alternative was using a ply board across a broad span of the wall to get into as many solid bits as possible.

The house is around 12 years old and in the UK and looks quite "new".

Comment: use a magnet to detect nail/screws and a pencil to mark it. You'll likely identify where the studs are.

Comment: Tried that didn't pick up any screws..  maybe magnet was too weak